# yii2 при валидации сбрасывает файл

Tags: php, yii2, изображения

Делаю форму с возможностью загрузки изображения. Делал такое и раньше, но сейчас возникли трудности.

Выбираю файл, нажимаю кнопку "сохранить", форма обновляется и "сбрасывает" файл, и пишет Please upload a file.

Делал vardump ошибок

```
                //$model->
                //var e = array(1) {
                //    [0]=> object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#104 (5) {
                //    # ["name"]=> string(5) "2.jpg"
                //    # ["tempName"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php4w7VSt"
                //    # ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
                //    # ["size"]=> int(74596) ["error"]=> int(0) } }
                //    #
                //    # string(2) "\n" array(1) {
                //    # [0]=> object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#104 (5) {
                //    # ["name"]=> string(5) "2.jpg"
                //    # ["tempName"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php4w7VSt"
                //    # ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"
                //    # ["size"]=> int(74596) ["error"]=> int(0) } }
                //    #
                //    # array(1) { ["imageFile"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Please upload a file." } }
```

**модель**

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

public $imageFile;

public function rules()
{
    return [[['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
```

**контроллер**

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
class EditAction extends Action{

    public function run($id = 0){
        $model = ($id?Publications::findOne($id) :new Publications());
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
           $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFile');
           if($model->validate()) {
              var_dump($model->title);die;//сюда уже не доходит
              if ($model->imageFile) {
```

**представление**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method'=>'post']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
     <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить статью', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

**скины**

[image: выбрали картинку]

[image: получили ошибку]

Comment: Покажите весь массив rules

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить тег form на правильные аттрибуты:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: У тега form который
    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
или который общий, где виджет ActiveForm
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method'=>'post']]); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Удалите  `'skipOnEmpty' => false`  в rules()

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Что даст предложеное решение?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте удалить `'skipOnEmpty' => false` из

```
return [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
```